# is Reduction from RE to coRE possible?

Tags: computability

I'm trying to figure out if it something that I can say for every 2 languages:

is Reduction from RE\R to coRE\R always not possible, and why?

(some thoughts about it: this reduction might be possible when for given language L it's both in RE and both in coRE (meaning it's in R,  but when it's RE\R and coRE\R, it is not possible)

another thought, can I use reduction from RE\R to prove that some language that in coRE is not in R?

Comment: Any problem is [Turing-reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) to its complement.

Comment: @Nathaniel
but given the following languages:
$$E_{T M}=\{\langle M\rangle: L(M)=\emptyset\}. \in coRE $$
$$A_{T M}=\{\langle M,w\rangle: M accepts w \} \in RE$$ 
I can't reduce from $$A_{T M} $$ to  $$E_{T M} $$

Comment: @Nathaniel someone?

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on what "reducible" means.

- If we mean *Turing reducible*, then every set (trivially) Turing-reduces to its complement, so in particular each r.e. set reduces to a co-r.e. set.
- If we mean *many-one reducible*, on the other hand, then **no** properly r.e. (= r.e. and not recursive) set reduces to any co-r.e. set. For suppose $A$ is properly r.e. and $B$ is co-r.e. If $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ were an $m$-reduction of $A$ to $B$, then we could recursively enumerate the complement of $A$ (put $x$ into $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ iff we see $f(x)$ leave $B$). This would make $A$ recursive.

In my experience, "reducible" in computer science almost always means "[resource-bounded] many-one reducible."